# Join results "generated" from two SELECT statements with different schemas into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

So I have the following SELECT statements:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.Award) AS US, SUBSTRING(CAST(M.Year as char(4)), 0 , 4)  AS Decade
FROM Movies M, Awards A
WHERE {SOME WHERE CLAUSE}
GROUP BY Decade;
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, SUBSTRING(CAST(A2.Year as char(4)), 0 , 4) AS Decade
FROM Awards A2
WHERE {SOME WHERE CLAUSE}
GROUP BY Decade;
```

The first one is "generating" a table with columns (*US*, *Decade*) and the second one is "generating" another table with columns (*Total*, *Decade*). I want to join those two tables so that I get a table (*US*, *Total*, *Decade*). How can I do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Put them in subqueries and do a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.US, a.decade, b.total FROM

  (SELECT COUNT(A.Award) AS US, SUBSTRING(CAST(M.Year as char(4)), 0 , 4)  AS Decade
  FROM Movies M, Awards A
  WHERE {SOME WHERE CLAUSE}
  GROUP BY Decade ) AS a

INNER JOIN

  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, SUBSTRING(CAST(A2.Year as char(4)), 0 , 4) AS Decade
  FROM Awards A2
  WHERE {SOME WHERE CLAUSE}
  GROUP BY Decade) AS b

ON a.decade = b.decade
```